# Assigning attributes from an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to build a form based off of column names I get from a PHP script, through AJAX, and a pre-defined array of column details. I am hoping to assign these pre-defined attributes to the incoming columns and build a form. For example, if I ever get the column "UserName" I want to to always be an < input >

**The template**

```
var template = {
  UserName : {
                label: "User Name:",
                type: "input"
  }
  UserId : {
              label: "User Id:",
              type: "text"
  }
}
```

**Incoming JSON array from AJAX request**

```
{"UserName":"bob", "UserId":"1"}
```

Now I need to somehow 'match' these. I myself am not sure exactly what to do here.

```
$.each(data, function(i,e){
  // if index (such as UserName) is found in template array, maybe add the attributes to it?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, use `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` to test if it exists, concatenate a string and use a ternary assignment to build a input element. You could also use an if statement if you wished.

```
var $html = '';
$.each(data, function(idx,v){
    $html += template.hasOwnProperty(idx)? '<input type="'+template[idx]['type']+'" name="'+idx+'"/>': '';
});
console.log($html);
```

[Here's your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bju498ox/)

Comment: If my JSON looks more like [{"UserName":"Bob","UserId":"1"}] I guess it is necessary to use two $.each statements to get to the element "UserName" ?

Comment: @user3822370 No. That is an array of objects. You should have multiple objects stored in the array, not an array for each object. That will make messy code. With your existing example, use: `$.each(data[0], function(idx, v){`

Comment: Yeah unfortunately when I send my JSON data from PHP, I have to break the assoc array and rebuild it (so I can encode BLOBs). So it ends up coming back nested like that.. [ {}, {}... ]

Comment: @user3822370 Yes, that's fine. You can iterate the existing array using the same methodology, `$.each(data[0], function(idx, obj){` now we're iterating the array. Then If you want to iterate each object, it's `$.each(obj, function(i, v){`

Comment: Just wondering, are nested each and even for loops inefficient?

Comment: @user3822370 Depends on how much data there is in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (and perhaps wordier) solution including label processing might be shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/q1p0auv6/).  The high level is based on the following code:

```
$(function () {
    var template = {
        UserName: {
            label: "User Name:",
            type: "input"
        },
        UserId: {
            label: "User Id:",
            type: "text"
        }
    };
    var data = {
        "UserName": "bob",
        "UserId": "1"
    };
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        if (template[key] != undefined) {
            $("#here").append($("<span>" + template[key].label + "</span>"));
            $("#here").append($("<input type=\"" + template[key].type + "\">"));
            $("#here").append($("<br>"));
        }
    });
});
```